# SmallTalk Challenge

Tags: windows-xp, smalltalk

How to boot Windows XP from Smalltalk Virtual Machine?

**UPD.** Sorry, guys :) It was a sort of joke... Actually I like this kind of questions, when we change the order of statements, So in that case it is possible to get interesting answers for different interpretation of such "reversed" questions :)

It's like a process of investigation if given operator (in terms of functional analysis) is bijective...

Comment: If you're asking for something sensible, I think you need to clarify, because it sounds like you don't even understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least with SqueakNOS you can directly boot your machine and don't even need a OS to run :)
http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/1762
http://squeaknos.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

You've got it backwards.  Langugage virtual machines like SmallTalk's and the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) are programs that run "virtual assembly code".  Virtualization software like VMWare run native assembly code in a virtual machine.  Windows XP is written in (mostly) C and C++, and is compiled to native code.

Language Virtual Machines work like this:

```
   [Smalltalk/Java Bytecode]
             |
             V
[SmallTalk/Java Bytecode Machine]
             |
             V
      [Windows/Linux]
             |
             V
      [Native Machine]
```

What you want is a virtulalization program like VMWare, or xVM Virtual Box that creates a virtual computer on top of a real computer, with no instruction conversion/mapping.

Comment: Unless the OP's asking "how do I write a virtualisation platform in Smalltalk?" !